# Can't set raycaster layers in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to set the raycaster layer to only cast on a single layer, as shown in the threejs docs: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster - But I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems super simple

```html
var scene = new THREE.Scene();  // Create scene

// Setup Camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    90, // FOV
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, // Aspect Ratio
    0.1, // Inner Plane
    1000, // Far Plane
);

// Setup renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

// Setup camera controls
var controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
camera.position.set( 5, 0, 3 );
camera.layers.enable(1);
controls.minDistance = 5;
controls.maxDistance = 50;
controls.maxPolarAngle = 1.5;
controls.enablePan = false; // Stops the right mouse drag movement
controls.update();

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);  // Enstates the renderer to the body I think

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {  // Allows the canvas to adjust dynamically to window size
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
})

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

raycaster.layers.set(0);
```

Comment: Please make sure that you are using a more recent version of `three.js`. `Raycaster.layers` was added with `r114`.

Answer (score 0):

##### This is probably due to your ThreeJS version.

This works for me:

```js
let scene = new THREE.Scene(); // Create scene

// Setup Camera
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  90, // FOV
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, // Aspect Ratio
  0.1, // Inner Plane
  1000, // Far Plane
);

// Setup renderer
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

// Setup camera controls
let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
camera.position.set(5, 0, 3);
camera.layers.enable(1);
controls.minDistance = 5;
controls.maxDistance = 50;
controls.maxPolarAngle = 1.5;
controls.enablePan = false; // Stops the right mouse drag movement
controls.update();

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); // Enstates the renderer to the body I think

window.addEventListener('resize', () => { // Allows the canvas to adjust dynamically to window size
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
})

let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

raycaster.layers.set(0);
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```